# delete session files after a time from creation

Tags: php, session, automation

I am saving my sessions in another directory from /temp directory.
say `/session` directory.( using `session_save_path("session")` )

also, there is a code to kill the session after 10 minuets from creation and logout.

but I mentioned that if the user logs in and for example shut down his computer, my log out and session destroy code doses not run, so the session file will remain in the session directory.

I wanted to know is there is a way to delete session files in `/session` after a time from creation?

I used this code for it

```
  if ($handle = opendir('sessions')) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (filectime($file)< (time()-600)) {  // 600 = 10*60
        unlink($file);
        }
    }
  }
```

but, not working, I think it couldn't get the creation time by `filectime($file)`

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks but I think I could solve it by myself

the solution was simple

```
  if ($handle = opendir('sessions')) {

  foreach (glob("sessions/sess_*") as $filename) {
    if (filemtime($filename) + 400 < time()) {
      @unlink($filename);
    }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need that. PHP itself implements a garbage collection mechanism to delete defunct session files. It's going to be much more efficient than anything else you could write yourself using PHP.

See the [session.gc_*](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) configuration options of PHP for more infos.

Comment: It seems that it works only with sessions in the /tmp directory I have 4 session files in there( my own session directory), from 4 days ago still alive !!

Comment: I'm quite sure it works with your current session path. Remember there's only a small chance that the GC mechanism actually starts each time you run your script to avoid too much overhead. By default, it's 1% chance each time you access a script using sessions.

Comment: so, how can I change the "session.gc_probability" to 100 ( it's default is 1 )

Comment: @safaali - That's not the right solution at all.  Causing the garbage collector to run on **every** session fetch is adding a lot of overhead.  Why not simply store an `expiryTime` as part of the session information, and check it when you start the session?  If it's too old, you can explicitly destroy it with `session_destroy()` and start fresh with a new session.

Answer (score 3):

I've done this before with a cron job that went in and deleted session files older than X (for some reason PHP's automatic cleanup wasn't doing the job).  Unfortunately that's probably not an option you'd have if this is on a managed host that doesn't give you the ability to set up cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Delete old sessions
  if (substr(ini_get('session.save_path'), 0, 4) != '/tmp') {
    foreach (glob(rtrim(ini_get('session.save_path'), '/') .'/sess_*') as $filename) {
      if (filemtime($filename) + ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') < time()) {
        @unlink($filename);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the session files directory
$dir = session_save_path("session");

//clear cache
clearstatcache();

// Open a directory, and read its contents

if (is_dir($dir)){

  // we iterate through entire directory
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
  while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

    //get the last acces date of each file
    @$time_stamp=fileatime($file);

    //check if it is older than... 600, and assign a text flag: with value "to delete" (when old enough) or "---" (when young enough)
    $to_delete = ($time_stamp<time()-600) ? 'to delete!' : '---';

    //format acces date to a human readible format
    @$date = date("F d Y H:i:s.",fileatime($file));

    //output stats on the screen
    echo "file:" . $file . "Last access: ".$date.", ".$to_delete."<br>";

    //INFO
    //depending on wishes, you can modify flow of the script using variables
    // particulary useful is $to_delete  -> you can easily covert it to true/false format
    //to control the scrip
  }

  closedir($dh);
  }

}
```