# Unlink() doesnt remove file

Tags: php, file, session, unlink

i have this code in logout.php

```
  session_start(); 
  $FileLink = 'tmp/sess_'.session_id();
      //echo $FileLink ; shows the tmp/sess_3386911cc664626ffb3664c478c8ad55 file
  unlink($FileLink); 
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
```

I have read many posts saying same method But i dont get the session file to be deleted .

anything is wrong?

i have tried most everything. if is file , iswritable , is readable , is path , changed the path to full path , nothing worked , just the session get unset and the file will be 0 byte but not deleted.

any suggestion thanks?

**EDIT** my php.ini

```
  session.save_handler = "files"
  session.save_path = "/home/website/public_html/gallery/tmp"
  session.use_cookies = 1
  session.use_only_cookies = 1
  session.name = "PHPSESSID"
  session.auto_start = 0
  session.cookie_lifetime = 0
  session.cookie_path = "/"
  session.cookie_domain = ""
  session.cookie_httponly = ""
  session.serialize_handler = "php"
  session.gc_probability = 1
  session.gc_divisor = 1000
  session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
  session.bug_compat_42 = ""
  session.bug_compat_warn = ""
  session.referer_check = ""
  session.entropy_length = 0
  session.cache_limiter = "nocache"
  session.cache_expire = 180
  session.use_trans_sid = 0
  session.hash_function = 0
  session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
```

**EDIT2**
folder permissions

tmp folder is 755 , and tried with 777 and still same , tried even if files are readable or writable and i got true they are.

Comment: I think tmp is the system tmp, which is located at the root directory, which is: /tmp, not tmp.

Comment: i have changed the full path but its wrong.

Comment: Tried to first unset and destroy, and then unlink?

Comment: have spents hours on this and have read all SO post which are same.

Comment: @PetervanderWal it saids `Warning: unlink(tmp/sess_): No such file or directory` meabs that session_id is unset and no file.

Comment: You may need to first check/set the session's variable taken from the other page it's logged out from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- didnt get you really.

Comment: For example: `$ses_id = session_id();` then doing `$FileLink = 'tmp/sess_'.session_id();` - Edit: *hold on*... thinking. I might be wrong. (this is a tricky one).

Comment: I take it that your other file created a session under a folder called `tmp/sess_3386911cc664626ffb3664c478c8ad55` as an example?

Comment: yes, session_id is created normal, and is same when i echo it here or in website , and yes this file is in tmp folder with that name you posted.

Comment: did you check `php.ini` to see what the [session save path](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)  (and other settings) are?

Comment: @CrayonViolent edited my question with  php.ini

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with the standard PHP garbage collection of session files?

Comment: *Hm...* permissions issue maybe? Did you try `chmod($FileLink, 0777)` after `$FileLink = 'tmp/sess_'.session_id();`? see if that will make it kick in?

Comment: on a side note.. you shouldn't have the session dir in a public dir like that. that's what leads to session hijacking

Comment: "it saids `Warning: unlink(tmp/sess_):`". I meant: `$FileLink = '..'; session_unset(); session_destroy(); unlink($FileLink);` Can't test it really, my server correctly deletes the file (even without unlink).

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited with permissions :)

Comment: Using `$FileLink = '/home/website/public_html/gallery/tmp/sess_'.session_id();` didn't work neither? I think you said that already.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i said it tried it

Comment: @Fred-ii- they are finished the suggestions :), this gonna not work :) ?

Comment: Something like `selinux` or `AppArmor` running on the server, preventing the deletion?

Comment: If you are able to `sudo su apache -`, you could try simply `rm`ing one of the session files to remove the PHP aspect from the troubleshooting.

Comment: @PetervanderWal this :O , i never heard about that , i dont know really. i ask the host about it ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was writing a piece of (test) code for you to try. I will post it in an answer below if you can give that a try and base yourself on it. @echo_Me (*crossing my fingers*) ;-)

Comment: @PatrickQ It makes me open my eyes , can you explain little bite ? you mean reduce probality ? i have tried reduce it to 0.01 `session.gc_probability` instead of 1 , and nothing happen

Comment: I'm just not sure why you're wanting to delete these files programmatically, when PHP will automatically delete them for you after what it considers to be a suitable amount of time (with some randomness added in too). Unless your site has absolutely massive amounts of traffic and/or you are storing enormous amounts of data in session, then having the session files hang around until PHP decides to delete them should not be an issue. Long story short, unless you have a specific and very good reason for wanting to delete these files, just let PHP do it for you.

Comment: @PatrickQ what i want is delete that file when user log out. how ever if i let php do it , it will be set by time, so even when user loged out the session file is still there by time.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using, I am seeing a non utf8 characters here:

```
echo $FileLink ; shows the tmp/sess_hkhgdfhghgöfhghggsöh file
```

I know on ubuntu those characters get replace by a ? mark, that could be the issue?

Try any of the following:

1) Do a readdir on the folder and output the filename:

```
if ($handle = opendir('tmp')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

2) Replace non alphanumeric to a question mark:

```
$FileLink = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '?', $FileLink);
unlink($FileLink);
```

Ultimately there is an issue with the session_id() giving you non utf8 characters, I am looking into that now.

3) Set the file ownership to NoBody by settings an invalid ID:

```
chown($FileLink, 666);
```

4) Create the session file yourself before creating the sessions:

```
$fp = fopen('tmp/sess_3386911cc664626ffb3664c478c8ad55', 'w+');
fclose($fp);
session_id('3386911cc664626ffb3664c478c8ad55');
session_start();
```

You can duplicate the algorithm PHP uses to create a session name. The delete should work fine after, I hope.

Comment: i have no specialcharacter in sess_filename . it was just typing in keyboard :)

Comment: Can you post the actual session name and are you manually setting the session name or the system is?

Comment: @echo_Me Try the following before Unlink: chown($FileLink, 666);

Comment: i got this `Warning: chown(): Operation not permitted`

Comment: This means you have no permissions to delete the file. What you could do, before you create your session, create the session file and set the ID to that file (since you created you have access to it). More on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723599/permission-for-session-directory. Added example on how you would do it.

Answer (score 0):

**For testing purposes only.**

I don't know if this will be useful or not, but my test code below proved to be successful.

```
<?php
session_start();

$ses_id = session_id();
echo $ses_id;

$filename = 'test_folder/sess_'.$ses_id;
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp,"");
fclose($fp);

unlink($filename);
```

---

### Edit

All I can think of at this point, is that you can try getting the session's variable from the previous page, then it could look something like:

[First page]

```
session_start(); 
$ses_id = "sess_" .session_id();

echo '<a href="check_session.php">Check session</a>';
```

[Logout page]

```
session_start(); 
$FileLink = 'tmp/sess_'.$ses_id;

unlink($FileLink); 
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

[Check session] (check_session.php)

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION)){
    echo "sess_" .session_id();
}
```

Comment: I understood what you want do , however file is not deleted , im nervous.

Comment: I would've have wanted to make a better script, but I don't have access to the actual session files on my server (*for some reason*)... and that was the closest I could get to replicate the problem. @echo_Me I'm at a loss right now, but if I think of anything else, I will keep you posted. So, doing a plain echo doesn't show anything eh? *Hm...* most bizarre.

Comment: :) , i very apreciate your effort dude :) , this took me 1 day :( .

Comment: You're welcome my friend. I noticed in another comment that you're using a Windows server. You may need to set special permissions. I'm on a Unix box myself so it's much easier for me. @echo_Me

Comment: windows xp im using , but this website is onlive not in localhost.

Comment: As Aziz mentioned, using `chown($FileLink, 666);` didn't work? @echo_Me

Comment: i writed him the answer of this in his comments.

Comment: Q: Can you actually see a physical (session) file in the `tmp` folder? @echo_Me

Comment: yes i can see them , they are stored :) , you clever :) i know you want see if they are stored , but they are , im deleting them manually :(.

Comment: LOL! No, I just wanted to know if "you" were able to see them. Once you can manage to "echo" the file(s), you will regain control. @echo_Me

Comment: @echo_Me Have a look at this answer (it might help) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2126179/

Comment: do i need to use `glob` ?

Comment: You might have to, but try removing it and see. You can try `foreach (("sessions/sess_*") as $filename)` but not sure if it will work. @echo_Me

Comment: Sessions can be a pain. Have a look under my **Edit** @echo_Me

Comment: When you get a chance @echo_Me [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22515588/) might also help.

Comment: @echo_Me So, any new developments?

Comment: thanks fred for caring , there is nothing new i just want leave this and do my chat by ajax instead of sessions. but i apreciate you caring ,

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help @echo_Me Take care :) and you're welcome on the +1 on your answer and thanks for the +1 ;-)